# Generate and populate a grid from points in a geopandas dataframe

Tags: python, dem, geopandas, array

**Context:**

I have a geopandas dataframe, with two columns

1. `'geometry'`: full of `shapely.geometry.point.Point`.
2. `'h_mean'`: gathering the height of a surface at those points

I want to create a 2D spatial grid which spatial footprint englobes the points, and where the lower left and upper right corners are the min and max points in the `'geometry'` column. Then, I want to populate in this grid (or array) the `'h_mean'` values of each point based on its coordinates.

**Problem:** How to code efficiently the grid generation and the population of the grid ?

**How I do it:**

My code is divided in 3 parts:

1. Generating the geopandas dataframe (just for the example, it is different in my real code)
2. Generating the grid (by using a Haversine function in order to calculate the shape of my grid)
3. Populating the grid (reusing the grid's shape to populate rather than `xarray`'s `.sel()` function that populates the grid by comparing to the closest coordinates.

**Code:**

```
import random
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import numpy as np


###### ----- GENERATE GEOPANDAS DATAFRAME ----- ######

# Lower left and upper right coordinates of the AOI
x_min = -140.51050737448583
x_max = -140.2348344860644
y_min = 59.7891540534345
y_max = 60.5585355551882

# Resolution of 30m
res = 30

# Number of random points to generate
num_random_points = 20  # Adjust as needed

# Lists to store generated heights and points
heights = []
points = []

# Generate random heights and points within the specified range
for _ in range(num_random_points):
    # Generate a random height between 0 and 1000 (adjust as needed)
    height = random.uniform(0, 1000)
    heights.append(height)

    # Generate random coordinates within the specified range
    x = random.uniform(x_min, x_max)
    y = random.uniform(y_min, y_max)

    # Create a Shapely Point object
    point = Point(x, y)
    points.append(point)

# Include the minimum and maximum points
min_point = Point(x_min, y_min)
max_point = Point(x_max, y_max)

# Add the minimum and maximum points to the lists
points.extend([min_point, max_point])
heights.extend([0, 0])  # Assign heights of 0 to the min and max points

# Create a GeoDataFrame from the generated data
data = {'geometry': points, 'h_mean': heights}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, crs='EPSG:4326')

# Print the generated GeoDataFrame
print(gdf)

##### ----- GENERATE GRID ----- #####
import math

# Function to calculate the distance between two points
def haversine_distance(lon1, lon2):
    # Convert longitude from degrees to radians
    lon1 = math.radians(lon1)
    lon2 = math.radians(lon2)

    # Radius of the Earth in meters
    earth_radius = 6371000  # Approximately 6,371 km

    # Haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = math.sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = earth_radius * c

    return distance


# Calculate the amount of cells of 30m spanning the x and y dimensions
dx = int(np.ceil(haversine_distance(x_max, x_min)/res))
dy = int(np.ceil(haversine_distance(y_max, y_min)/res))

# Create an array with dimensions dx by dy
grid_values = np.full((dx, dy), np.nan)

# Calculate the x and y steps between each 30m cell
step_x = np.abs((x_max - x_min))/dx
step_y = np.abs((y_max - y_min))/dy

# Create the x and y coordinates arrays
x_coords = np.array([x_min + i * step_x for i in range(dx)])
y_coords = np.array([y_min + i * step_y for i in range(dy)])




##### ----- POPULATE GRID ----- #####

# Iterate through points and populate the grid
for point, height in zip(points, heights):
    x_idx = int((point.x - x_min) / step_x)
    y_idx = int((point.y - y_min) / step_y)
    
    # Check if the indices are within the grid dimensions
    if 0 <= x_idx < dx and 0 <= y_idx < dy:
        grid_values[x_idx, y_idx] = height
```

Comment: This seems like a code review issue (something we don't generally do). The question you ask isn't really answerable -- "efficient" is subjective (relative to what?).

Comment: I should reformulate. Basically I wanted to know if anybody had already coded a way to generate a 2D grid from a geopandas dataframe and put it in a package or something similar